# How to update the version of "System.IO.Packaging"?

Tags: c#

When I was trying an example in "Microsoft's C# Tutorial", I get the following error.

CS1069
The type name 'PackageRelationship' could not be found in the namespace 'System.IO.Packaging'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.IO.Packaging, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Here is the sample code:

```
...
using System.IO.Packaging;
public static class LocalExtensions
{
    public static string StringConcatenate(this IEnumerable<string> source)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string s in source)
            sb.Append(s);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static string StringConcatenate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, string> func)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (T item in source)
            sb.Append(func(item));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static string StringConcatenate(this IEnumerable<string> source, string separator)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string s in source)
            sb.Append(s).Append(separator);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static string StringConcatenate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, string> func, string separator)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (T item in source)
            sb.Append(func(item)).Append(separator);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static string ParagraphText(XElement e)
    {
        XNamespace w = e.Name.Namespace;
        return e
        .Elements(w + "r")
        .Elements(w + "t")
        .StringConcatenate(element => (string)element);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string fileName = "SampleDoc.docx";
        const string documentRelationshipType =
        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument";
        const string stylesRelationshipType =
        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles";
        const string wordmlNamespace =
        "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        XNamespace w = wordmlNamespace;
        XDocument xDoc = null;
        XDocument styleDoc = null;
        using (Package wdPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `NuGet` to update your assembly: right click the porject -> **Manage NuGet packages** -> Input 'Packaging' in the **Browse** tab -> Do your **Upgrade** or **Install**.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install System.IO.Packaging nuget package.

- Right click on your project
- Select **Manage Nuget Package** option
- Under browse tab search for System.IO.Packging. and
- click  on install button fro right side pane.

[image]